# Python - Write a function that returns a day name

Tags: python-3.x

I have trouble in regards to a program. So I am trying to write a function that returns the name of a day. (Ex: 1.1.2014 is Wednesday) I am strictly dealing with only the year 2014. The inputs that I will have are d = day, m = month.

This is what I have so far.

```
def day(d,m): # Function for determining day name for a given date.
    """Where m is an integer from 1 through 12 expressing a month, and d is an integer from 
    1 through 31 expressing the day-part of a date in 2014."""

    if 1<=m<=12:
        return 

    elif 1<=d<=31:
        return ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa']

    else:
        return "Error"
```

Comment: If you want a formula for this, start [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week). The [Doomsday method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) would not be hard to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html).

```
import datetime as DT
def day(d,m): # Function for determining day name for a given date.
    """Where m is an integer from 1 through 12 expressing a month, and d is an
    integer from 1 through 31 expressing the day-part of a date in 2014."""

    date = DT.date(2014, m, d)    # 1
    return date.strftime('%A')
```

This will raise a ValueError if `2014/m/d` is not a valid date. It is usually preferable to raise an Exception than returning a string like `"Error"`.

Comment: I was thinking about using that. However, I wanted to see if its possible to do it only with if, elif, and else statements.